# Can't change system variable "Path" for netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, windows-7, path, system-variable

I downloaded Netbeans because I wanted to start learning C++. I downloaded the compiler, debugger, and make utility from cygwin. In order to complete the process of setting up my IDE I need to modify the system variable Path to reflect my new cygwin installation.

So here is what I do:

1. type var into windows search
2. click on Path in the system variables

Here is where the issue arises. The instructions I am reading tell me to edit the Path variable, but the buttons are unclickable. They remain faded even after clicking Path. When I double click the Path variable I hear the windows "error" chime.

I don't know why I can't modify the Path system variable. I have ensured that my account (the only one on the computer) is an administrator. I am running windows 7 if that makes a difference.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it just now. Even though the end destination is the same, typing var into the search bar opens the environment variable window, but prevents editing. However, if you right click Computer, select properties, select advanced settings, then click on environment variables, even though you're in the same location, the variables are then editable.